# Unable to connect to the remote server vb.net Client.UploadFile

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to upload a file with vb code.

I checked at https://www.infobyip.com/ftptest.php with this credentials and it is working :
Host : mydomain.gr
Port : 21
Login : mylogin
Pasword : mypsw
Directory :/image/catalog

My vb code is that:

```
Dim fname As String = "Images\Zar-" & Path.GetFileName(LocalDT(0)("ZarImageUrl").ToString)
            Dim Client As New WebClient
            Client.DownloadFile(LocalDT(0)("ZarImageUrl").ToString, Server.MapPath(fname))
            Client.Dispose()
            Upload("ftp://www.mydomain.gr", "mylogin", "mypsw", Server.MapPath(fname))
 Using Client As New WebClient
            Client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)
            Client.UploadFile(ftpServer + "/image/catalog/" + New FileInfo(filename).Name, "STOR", filename)
        End Using
```

I am getting this error : Unable to connect to the remote server 
Any idea?

Comment: Never put your credentials on a public forum, none the less dont put your credentials on some random site to check your credentials, bad idea! I would suggest changing them now...

Comment: It is not real credentials, but thank you for your suggestion!